# NPing gives significantly less time on `TCP Connect` than `TCP`

Tags: ping, latency, nmap

I'm using NPing (NMap's pinging tool) to measure latency on specific servers that may not respond to ICMP. Also, servers do not usually run HTTP(S) and I only check latency on a specific TCP port related to the game counter-strike.

I always try ICMP, TCP, and TCP-Connect and I perform them separately. My method is:

- Try ICMP (`nping --icmp dstip -p dstport`)
- Then, try TCP (`nping --tcp dstip -p dstport`)
- Then, try TCP-CONNECT (`nping --tcp-connect dstip -p dstport`).
- Get the lowest latency from all of them.

In my intuition, expected behavior should be

`ICMP latency >= TCP-Connect latency >= TCP latency`

What actually happens is that

`ICMP latency >= TCP latency >>> TCP-Connect latency` (where >>> stands for "a lot greater")

To give you an idea, in one server ICMP yields a timeout, TCP gets around `180ms`, and TCP-Connect only gives around `3ms`.

Any ideas on why this could happen?

**EDIT1**:
The `tcptraceroute` tool also gives me `3ms`. Both are very close and connect via an IXP. See below:

```
~$ sudo tcptraceroute dstip dstport
Selected device ens3, address 172.16.1.6, port 58803 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to dstip on TCP port dstport, 30 hops max
 1  my_localip (172.16.1.6) 0.139 ms  0.131 ms  0.155 ms
 2  my_isp_globalip  0.288 ms  0.233 ms  0.264 ms
 3  my_isp_bordergw  1.855 ms  0.311 ms  0.257 ms
 4  IXP_router_name (IXP_router_ip)  0.570 ms  0.420 ms  0.482 ms
 5  dst_bordergw  2.820 ms  2.967 ms  3.145 ms
 6  dst_internalrouter  2.736 ms  3.665 ms  2.331 ms
 7  dstname (dstip) [open]  3.095 ms  3.088 ms  3.145 ms
```

Still... Why would NPing's TCP mode give such a long delay?

**EDIT2**:
According to `tcpdump`, in TCP mode, TCP Syn response comes in around `3 to 6ms`. So why would NPing inform me a `180ms` latency?

Data: https://pastebin.com/v4mgacTR